# Actual 'last updated' date with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, dynamic

I have a webpage (i.e., a single-page website) and **I want to add a script showing the last time the page was updated (by me)**, that is, the last time the source HTML file changed.

**If I use this code inside the HTML document**

```js
document.write(document.lastModified)
```

```html
Last updated on
```

**I get the current date (I mean, each time I refresh the page, the date changes)**, I guess because actually the file *is being changed* by the script.

So, what can I do??

Comment: I get the same behaviour with

```
Last updated on <span id="lastupdated"></span>.
<script>
    document.getElementById("lastupdated").innerHTML = document.lastModified;
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the `lastModified` method is spotty at best. This method only works for truly static sites since dynamic sites are generating the HTML page when requested.

Even then, it seems that the `lastModified` method just returns the current date when the last modified date is unknown. [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified) makes this very clear:

> Files without a known last modified date return the current date.
>   - [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified)

If you are not able to programmatically produce your last modified date and you're just working with a single page static site, it may be less headache to just hard-code this information into the page.

Comment: Yes... I wanted to avoid that, but maybe that's the simplest solution.

Comment: If you're working with a single static file, I'd say likely so. Especially if you are the only author/editor of the page. It may also be worth knowing how your hosting provider serves their files, that might provide a little more insight to whether it's a hosting problem or a page problem.